# Fatal error: unexpected found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Tags: arrays, model-view-controller, swift3

I have a problem with an array of data, in this data array I send the name of 6 images so that later they are loaded in a CollectionView, the 6 images load well, without any problem, but when I add a String value to send it gives me a error that is empty:

This is my class where is my data array:

```
 import UIKit

class HBook{
    var imagenB: UIImage!
    var estatus: String!

    init(estatus: String, imagenB: UIImage) {

        self.estatus = estatus
        self.imagenB = imagenB
    }

    class func getData() -> [HBook]{

        let rawData = [
            ["imagenB":"book1"],
            ["imagenB":"book2"],
            ["imagenB":"book3"],
            ["imagenB":"book4"],
            ["imagenB":"book5"],
            ["imagenB":"book6"],
            ["estatus":"No reservado"]
        ]

        var hbook:[HBook] = []

        for item in rawData{
            hbook.append(HBook(estatus: item["estatus"]!, imagenB: UIImage(named: item["imagenB"]!)!))   
        }
        return hbook
    }
}
```

I print my data array to see which variable is empty, but apparently all have an assigned value:

[image]

I do not know why I'm sending an empty value.

This information was retrieved in another class that has a CollectionView and a Label, the method where I passed the information is in the cellForItemAt method:

```
class DetailViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

    @IBOutlet weak var contenedorCollection: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var myCollection: UICollectionView!
    @IBOutlet weak var pages: UIPageControl!
    @IBOutlet weak var estatus: UILabel!

    var hbook = HBook.getData()
    var nombreH = ""

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        pages.numberOfPages = hbook.count
        self.title = nombreH

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return hbook.count
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! CellCollectionViewCell

        cell.imageview.image = hbook[indexPath.row].imagenB
        estatus.text = hbook[indexPath.row].estatus
        return cell
    }
```

Comment: why you are setting estatus.text = hbook[indexPath.row].estatus in cellForItem mehtod as estatus label is not part of collection view

Comment: @Enrique Why are unwrapping it force fully ?? I will always give you crash. Try using 'if let' or guard statement for unwrapping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is in data class. Please replace your HBook class with following code and it will work without any further change :

```
class HBook{
var imagenB: UIImage?
var estatus: String?

init(estatus: String? = nil, imagenB: UIImage? = nil) {

    self.estatus = estatus
    self.imagenB = imagenB
}

class func getData() -> [HBook]{

    let rawData = [
        ["imagenB":"book1","estatus":"No reservado"],
        ["imagenB":"book2","estatus":"No reservado"],
        ["imagenB":"book3","estatus":"No reservado"],
        ["imagenB":"book4","estatus":"No reservado"],
        ["imagenB":"book5","estatus":"No reservado"],
        ["imagenB":"book6","estatus":"No reservado"]
    ]

    var hbook:[HBook] = []

    for item in rawData{
        if let image = item["itemnB"]{
            hbook.append(HBook(estatus: item["estatus"], imagenB:UIImage(named:image)))
        }else{
            hbook.append(HBook(estatus: item["estatus"]))
        }
    }
    return hbook
}
```

}

Comment: Yes, you're right, your solution helped me solve the problem, but I have a question, is there any way to avoid adding the status in each of the values ​​of the fixes?
I mean this:

["imagenb":["book1","book2,"book3,"book4","book5"]],
["estatus":"No reservado"]

Comment: @Enrique: In order to do that you need to take a dictionary in place of array which will have array for key "imagenb" and string for key "estatus".